# дизайн с четырьмя квадратами, как окошко, и чтоб можно было сдвигать границы взяв за центральное перекрестье

Tags: html, frame

[image: дизайн "окошко"]

хотелось бы чтобы взяв за перекрестье можно было изменять ширину фреймов и чтобы в них работали скроллы. Какую технологию лучше использовать? frameset, grid, flex?